# Quitting a job under a unique circumstances

Tags: quitting

I have been with this company for a year. Nothing substantial has happened that would constitute me leaving except I know this is not what I want to do, never wanted. The company doesn't offer insurance and I have had some health issues and after me having to have to take off a substantial amount of days ( approx around 6-8 weeks throughout the year ) I am now not getting paid for missed days. They have used my sick days and vacation days towards those days I took off.

The company is not bad, and bosses are nice people and we get along fine but its not for me. Also, I have to mention that when I was hired, I was suppose to get a raise in 3 months because original salary requirement was not met but was promised the talk in 3 months for a significant raise. I also mentioned that certain aspects of my job requirement I did not know and there would be a learning curve. Now they are expecting me to complete a project and I keep pushing the deadline over and over as I cant figure out how to make it happen, I keep telling them I did not know how to do it therefore delays are inevitable. They are getting frustrated, I understand that and I do understand that I have to deliver but if it is something I do not know I dont know what to tell them.

Please help me figure out how to get out of there gracefully and make it right by everyone. I really dont want to be there anymore I am not happy and dread going to work, which is a first because I love what I do and I feel like I am mistreating myself first and foremost, to the point that I dont even want to give the 2 weeks notice... The question is: I guess I am looking for advice or a solution as to what is the right way to do it? Do I have to give 2 weeks notice? Do I have to do it in person, email... etc?

Comment: well I guess I am looking for an advise or a solution as to what is the right way to do it? Do I have to give 2 weeks notice? Do i have to do it in person, email..etc?

Comment: ive edited the question

Comment: What's unique about your situation? You don't like your job, and you want leave. "Do I have to do it in person?" Yes! Adults have to do hard things.

Answer (score 7):

> Please help me figure out how to get out of there gracefully and make
>   it right by everyone. I really dont want to be there anymore I am not
>   happy and dread going to work, which is a first because I love what I
>   do and I feel like I am mistreating myself first and foremost, to the
>   point that I dont even want to give the 2 weeks notice... The question
>   is: I guess I am looking for advice or a solution as to what is the
>   right way to do it? Do I have to give 2 weeks notice? Do I have to do
>   it in person, email... etc?

If you want to exit gracefully and do right by everyone, you

- Find your next job first. That way, you don't make a mistake and take the wrong job due to financial pressure
- Resign in person to your boss
- Give 2 weeks notice
- Work your notice period professionally, giving your full attention to the tasks your company asks of you
- Thank people on the way out, even if you don't really like it there
- Say only good things about your company if asked

If you don't care about the "gracefully", "make it right by everyone" or "right way to do it" parts, then you could do whatever you want.

(I assume you are in the US. Let me know if that's not the case. Rules and customs differ elsewhere.)